# Angular overriding angular material, for 3 different components. Having similar material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have 3 components, which has these angular materials

1. mat-forms inside the mat-card
2. mat-expansion panel inside mat-card
3. pagination card, inside a card.
   So when I try to override the CSS styles using View Encapsulation, like this

```
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
      host:{"class": "app-forms"}// component name here
```

I overrode the form's components CSS styles. IT works fine until I navigate to a different component and when I come back the forms component styles are broken. And even other components styles are Broken. (The forms components take the style of other components card styles)

I tried using /deep/ as it is deprecated, didn't work for me
I understand why this is happening I'm not able to find any solution on how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add your own classes to the material component and override the material classes by your own class

for example

```
<mat-form-field class="custom-form-field"></mat-form-field>
```

and in `styles.css` file

```
.custom-form-field {
  // your styles
}

.custom-form-field .mat-input-element {
  // your styles for the inner material(html) elements
}
```

Comment: but inside mat-form-field there are more like mat-label, mat-input. how do I customize those? do I have to give class for even those? because I can't do it otherwise. inside a form there are input fields, labels,dropdowns and I want to change even those.

Comment: @HemanthGirimath when you will add your own class to the material element, like as the example above. After you can customize all of the inside elements depending on your own class. it will help you don't break existing material styles, and apply yours by the custom class.

Comment: Also, you don't need to add your custom class to the inside elements, more about CSS selectors you can find here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: thank you, it worked. really appreciate it. But with SCSS it's gonna be easy to do this rite? or is it the same process.